# Problem in setting up emoji button in react using Emoji Mart

Tags: reactjs, npm, emoji

This is my code for a realtime chat app. I am trying to setup an emoji button inside of the typing area but it did not work. I tried all version of chatgpt but in vain. Mainly chatgpt has an old knowledge of the Emoji Mart package.

My code is the following:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Button, Col, Form, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { AppContext } from "../context/appContext";
import "./MessageForm.css";
import data from '@emoji-mart/data'
import Picker from '@emoji-mart/react'

function MessageForm() {
    const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
    const user = useSelector((state) => state.user);
    const { socket, currentRoom, setMessages, messages, privateMemberMsg } = useContext(AppContext);
    const messageEndRef = useRef(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        scrollToBottom();
    }, [messages]);

    function getFormattedDate() {
        const date = new Date();
        const year = date.getFullYear();
        let month = (1 + date.getMonth()).toString();

        month = month.length > 1 ? month : "0" + month;
        let day = date.getDate().toString();

        day = day.length > 1 ? day : "0" + day;

        return month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
    }

    function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    function scrollToBottom() {
        messageEndRef.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
    }

    const todayDate = getFormattedDate();

    socket.off("room-messages").on("room-messages", (roomMessages) => {
        setMessages(roomMessages);
    });

    function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!message) return;
        const today = new Date();
        const minutes = today.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + today.getMinutes() : today.getMinutes();
        const time = today.getHours() + ":" + minutes;
        const roomId = currentRoom;
        socket.emit("message-room", roomId, message, user, time, todayDate);
        setMessage("");
    }
    return (
        <>
            <div className="messages-output">
                {user && !privateMemberMsg?._id && <div className="alert alert-info">You are in the {currentRoom} room</div>}
                {user && privateMemberMsg?._id && (
                    <>
                        <div className="alert alert-info conversation-info">
                            <div>
                                Your conversation with {privateMemberMsg.name} <img src={privateMemberMsg.picture} className="conversation-profile-pic" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </>
                )}
                {!user && <div className="alert alert-danger">Please login</div>}

                {user &&
                    messages.map(({ _id: date, messagesByDate }, idx) => (
                        <div key={idx}>
                            <p className="alert alert-info text-center message-date-indicator">{date}</p>
                            {messagesByDate?.map(({ content, time, from: sender }, msgIdx) => (
                                <div className={sender?.email == user?.email ? "message" : "incoming-message"} key={msgIdx}>
                                    <div className="message-inner">
                                        <div className="d-flex align-items-center mb-3">
                                            <img src={sender.picture} style={{ width: 35, height: 35, objectFit: "cover", borderRadius: "50%", marginRight: 10 }} />
                                            <p className="message-sender">{sender._id == user?._id ? "You" : sender.name}</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <p className="message-content">{content}</p>
                                        <p className="message-timestamp-left">{time}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            ))}
                        </div>
                    ))}
                <div ref={messageEndRef} />
            </div>
            <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <Row>
                    <Col md={11}>
                        <Form.Group>
                            <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Your message" disabled={!user} value={message} onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}></Form.Control>
    <span><Picker data={data} onEmojiSelect={message.addemoji} /></span>

                        </Form.Group>
                    </Col>
                    <Col md={1}>
                        <Button variant="primary" type="submit" style={{ width: "100%", backgroundColor: "orange" }} disabled={!user}>
                            <i className="fas fa-paper-plane"></i>
                        </Button>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Form>
        </>
    );
}

export default MessageForm;
```

I want an emoji button (maybe a smile face) inside of the typing input when the emoji is clicked it is inserted as an emoji in the typing input and when sent it is rendered correctly in the message-component box. I have been trying for days to get through it but I can't.